# Squared Exponential Basis Function - Can you explain the dimensionality please?

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-trick

So I am studying kernel functions and I am stuck on a problem. For a squared exponential kernel

$\kappa(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j) = \sigma_f^2 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2l^2}
  (\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j)^T
  (\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j)\right)\tag{10}$

Can $\mathbf{x_i}$ and $\mathbf{x_j}$ have different dimensions?

To this function I would like to input an array (matrix) of size $ n_1 \times m$ and another matrix $Y$ of size $n_2 \times m$. Initially I thought this would just be the outer product of $ X$ and $Y$ but now I am unsure, especially since they are of different sizes

**EDIT**

In the following form how would this work?

$K = (k(\mathbf{x_p}, \mathbf{y_q}))_{p,q} = \left( \sigma_f^2 \exp\left( - \dfrac{1}{2l^2} \| \mathbf{x_p} - \mathbf{y_q}\|^2 \right) \right)_{p,q}$

Can the squared exponential kernel be computed? Initially I thought it would just be an outer product but that does not give me the output I seek. Should it be some different computation?

Comment: You subtract $x_{j}$ from $x_{i}$, so they cannot be different. You cannot subtract an element of $\underline{x_{j}}$ from a dimension that doesn't exist.

Comment: This is what I thought. However please see my question as I have added an EDIT